# In React components, is it "bad practice" to refer to child components outside of the render/return?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm scaffolding a component rebuild. It previously had 2 breakpoints but will now have 4. The 2 current breakpoints are piled into a single component with a grand-master ternary showing one or the other of full JSX... yeah, 2 sets of mostly similar JSX output, it's a big component using only 1 half or the other.

I'm going to break out the 2 existing breakpoints into sub components, with the 3rd and 4th sizes as well, and I'm trying to work out a system that will choose which of the 4 components to show.

Here's a copy paste of what I have concepted on stackblitz.com

```
export default function App() {
  const chooser = 2;
  const enumb = {
    [0]: <Slap />,
    [1]: <Bammy />,
    [2]: <Weeds />,
  };

  const between = (x, min, max) => {
    return x >= min && x <= max;
  };
  const show = !between(chooser, 0, 2) ? 0 : chooser;

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Hello StackBlitz!</h1>
      {enumb[show]}
      {show}
    </div>
  );
}

const Bammy = () => {
  return <div>component Bammy</div>;
};

const Weeds = () => {
  return <div>component Weeds</div>;
};

const Slap = () => {
  return <div>component Slap</div>;
};
```

---

Note: Change the value of `chooser` to display the chosen component. `show` and `between()` are a sanity check limiter to fallback to a valid value.

So my main questions is about the `{enumb[show]}` down in the `return` statement:

- **Is it "bad practice" to make reference to (or include) child components ***outside*** of the return/render of the parent component?** *(While this doesn't look too bad right here, the props tree is pretty big enough to make it "complex" reading.)*
- **Is there a performance/state/rerender issue with this method of rendering child components??**

The 2ndary question is: what would be the best way to do the `enumb` reference/decision down in the return? (btw I'd like to avoid `switch/case` cuz it just seems verbose.)

Answer (score 1):

There's no penalty for doing so. Best practices are determined by your co-workers.

[Here's an example showing there's no performance hit](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-b2uwcc)

If I was to evaluate your code in code review (I know it's probably purely for demonstration purposes) then I would tell you to move the static stuff outside your render method, [like this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-o5u1nt)

```js
const enumb = {
  [0]: Slap,
  [1]: Bammy,
  [2]: Weeds
};

const between = (x, min, max) => {
  return x >= min && x <= max;
};

export default function App() {
  const chooser = 2; // let's pretend chooser is a prop passed into App
  const show = !between(chooser, 0, 2) ? 0 : chooser;
  const Cmp = enumb[show];

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Hello StackBlitz!</h1>
      <Cmp />
      {show}
    </div>
  );
}
```